# Trying to execute a terminal command from an application launcher does not work

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have downloaded the anaconda development suit to learn python (as recommended by the course staff) but it doesn't add a launcher in Linux, so I created a custom one.

When I enter `anaconda-navigator` in the terminal it will open up the program, but if I use that command in the "execute" field when creating the custom launcher, double clicking the launcher will throw an error. I have made the .desktop file executable, so I have no idea what's wrong or how to fix it.

[image: Program opening after entering the command in the terminal]

[image: Program not opening when trying to use a launcher with the same command in the "execute" field]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run `which anaconda-navigator` what results do you get?

Comment: it gave me the executable address! `/home/nigra/.anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator` I placed that one in the execute field and now the launcher works! Thanks a lot. Please reply so I can mark it as correct :) <3

Comment: Added an answer!

Comment: @LucasD'Abate how did you install anaconda-navigator pls?

Comment: @solfish sorry for taking so long! I downloaded the program from their website. It comes as an .sh file. You open it with the terminal by navigating to the file directory and then entering `$ bash ./Anaconda-version.sh` (replace with the name of the file you downloaded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which` command to find the exact location of the `anaconda-navigator` then place that in the `Exec` field in your `.desktop` file:

```
Exec=/home/nigra/.anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator
```